# Jquery Lightbox not working with MasterPage

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, master-pages, lightbox

I have used lightbox and variations before but am having trouble getting it to work properly.  Hoping someone has some advice as I'm far from an expert in javascript.  The C#/ASP website has a MasterPage and every other page uses that MasterPage.  The link is also generated dynamically through code.  I've had two outcomes in my testing: either it just works like a normal link and redirects me to the image or it does nothing when I click on it.

In MasterPage Head:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

In Page code:

```
DynLink.ImageUrl = "~/PostPhotos/Thumbnails/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.Photo) +     "_thumb100_100" + Path.GetExtension(image.Photo).Replace("//","/"); 
DynLink.NavigateUrl = "~/PostPhotos/Thumbnails/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.Photo) + "_thumblowres" + Path.GetExtension(image.Photo); 
DynLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "lightbox");
```

The link that is generated (via firebug inspect):

```
<a href="PostPhotos/Thumbnails/grumpy_cat_christmas_9_thumblowres.jpg" rel="lightbox">
<img alt="" src="PostPhotos/Thumbnails/grumpy_cat_christmas_9_thumb100_100.jpg">
</a>
```

The image shows up fine, and when I inspect it with firebug everything seems fine (it has the 'rel' attribute etc.).

Comment: Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension

the PATH VARIABLE SHOULD HAVE the path "~/PostPhotos/Thumbnails/", check in run time source, you may be getting wrong file path/ SRC,

Comment: Have you initialized the lightbox? $(function() { //Lightbox init });

Comment: I didn't realise you had to initialize it?  from the examples I've seen you just reference the .js file and add the rel part to the link?  That's all I've done before and had success

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are configuring lightbox at document.ready somewhere in master page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('YourLightBoxSelector').lightbox(); 

});
```

Comment: added this:       
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('YourLightBoxSelector').lightbox(); 

});
</script>
...but it didn't solve anything =/

Answer (score 0):

since your element is added dynamically ... calling  lightbox, after the dynamically generated element is appended in the document, will work....

```
DynLink.ImageUrl = "~/PostPhotos/Thumbnails/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.Photo) +     "_thumb100_100" + Path.GetExtension(image.Photo).Replace("//","/"); 
DynLink.NavigateUrl = "~/PostPhotos/Thumbnails/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image.Photo) + "_thumblowres" + Path.GetExtension(image.Photo); 
DynLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "lightbox");
//your append code..
$('#dynamicelementID').lightbox();
```

Comment: sorry adding that line doesn't compile, is that meant to be in javascript or c#??